# multiple json to csv using pandas python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

trying to convert multiple json files to 1 csv file
tried 2 ways,
first one using pandas ,
second using json and csv writer

about my json

```
keys are unordered and some keys are different in every file
```

code using writer

```
file_list=os.listdir('output')
count = 0
for file in file_list:
    dict={}
    file_path = "output/" + file
    with open(file_path,'r') as f:
        jsonData=json.load(f)
        datafile=open('data.csv','a')
        csv_writer = csv.writer(datafile)
        if count == 0:
            header = jsonData.keys()
            csv_writer.writerow(header)
            count += 1
            csv_writer.writerow(jsonData.values())
        if count == 1:
            csv_writer.writerow(jsonData.values())

        datafile.close()
```

problem

```
bcoz my data is unordered and different keys so in my csv file wrong value is coming under wrong header
```

code using pandas

```
for file in file_list:
    dict={}
    file_path = "output/" + file
    with open(file_path,'r') as f:
        jsonData=json.load(f)
        for j in jsonData:


            dict.update({j:[jsonData[j]]})
        df=pd.DataFrame(dict)
        df.to_csv("hello.csv")
```

problem

```
i dont know how to append in pandas 
so this is showing only 2 rows bcoz of my last json file i guess
```

inside my json

Comment: Should each json file be one row in the output? Could you provide one or two short example json files and maybe even a list of all possible keys, that should appear in the csv output?

Comment: header    ```Solutions, account_number ,actual_reading_current, actual_reading_previous address, amount_due,```
values  ```$7.90  72xxx06,,,, 16839,,, 16586 ,,, T B FAIR LAWN BORO NJ 07410 ,,,48.1```

Comment: This is the header that you want in your csv file? Could you please also give me a dummy json file to test? And please either use a file sharing service or alter your original post, comments don't allow for a lot of formatting.

Comment: @ClF3 added json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import pathlib

data_path = pathlib.Path('.')
keys = ['Solutions', 'account_number', 'actual_reading_current','actual_reading_previous', 'address', 'amount_due']
dat = dict([(k, []) for k in keys])

for jfile in data_path.glob('*.json'):
    with jfile.open('r') as ifile:
        json_data = json.load(ifile)
    for key in keys:
        dat[key].append(json_data[key][0] if key in json_data else None)

result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dat)
result.to_csv('result.csv')
```

I first define a dictionary containing the columns that I want.
Then I read in the json files and append them as rows to the dictionary.

Note, that I had to edit your json files, one was missing a ending quote and I had to replace the single quotes by double quotes.

Comment: this error is coming```dat[key].append(json_data[key][0] if key in json_data else None)
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible that some json files are structured differently, e.g. not all values are inside of a list? If that is the case you can either make all json files use the same format or check inside the main loop if json_data[key] is a list.

Comment: okay data i have show above is i edited it into list through my code ,,,,values are not into list inside my json they are normal strings

Comment: inside dat after first loop\  ```{' Solutions': ['$'], 'account_number': [], 'actual_reading_current': [], 'actual_reading_previous': [], 'address': [], 'amount_due': [], 'average_supply': [],  'rate': [], 'total_amount_debt': [], 'total_electric_charge': [], 'total_electric_delivery_charge': [], 'total_electricity_used': []}```

Comment: I wont change my answer, while your json format stays in the original post. But to work with the different format, change 'json_data[key][0] if key in json_data else None' to 'json_data.get(key, None)'. You no longer need to take the value out of the array, simply get the key and if the key is not there, return None.